# Checkboxes get disabled by theirself

Tags: c++-cli

i have a problem in the application that i'm currently trying to make. In checkboxs' properties it says it's Enabled = True but after i debug and open it they all are disabled. Why did this happen? Any helps?

Comment: Can't help without seeing at least some of the code. You are sure you are not setting that somewhere else in the program?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here may be one of terminology. You're accessing the 'Enabled' property, but I think you may want the 'Checked' property.

The Enabled property is set by you, and controls whether the user can click on the checkbox or not. The Checked property is set either by you or by the user, and it changes whenever the user clicks on the checkbox.

Here's a picture of four checkboxes:

- Check Box One is **Enabled**, and not Checked.
- Check Box Two is **Enabled**, and **Checked**.
- Check Box Three is not Enabled, and not Checked.
- Check Box Four is not Enabled, and **Checked**.

[image]